# GLSL Water shader normals morph as light passes over?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, processing, shader

I decided to follow [the classic guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems/part-i-natural-effects/chapter-1-effective-water-simulation-physical-models) for writing a basic GLSL water shaders using the sum of sines method. I attempted to implement it inside of Processing 5, where I made a field of vertices in a PShape to make a mesh to mess with. I then overwrote the default shaders with my own vertex and fragment shaders, and I dropped in a directional light so I can actually see the normals. I made sure the directional light was movable as well so I could see if the normals work from all angles.

I got the waves to form height correctly and I had some form of normals workings, but the normals are interacting really strange. When my light passes across the center axis of my water plane, the normals seem to morph between the different waves and change based on the light angle. The gif I captured was too large to post in line, so I'm sure seeing it would explain better than my words:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqcpY.jpg

You should maximize the link to see the whole picture. Note how as the light pans from left to right, the normals of the waves seem to morph between two sets? This is especially apparent as it crosses center. It's like the normals are inconsistent based on the direction the object is being lit from.

The sphere in the middle is a normal sphere using the standard Processing shader. I left it there as reference to see the waves as well as confirm where my lighting was and that it was working fine.

Any ideas what I did wrong? I know I did some math incorrectly somewhere.

EDIT: Was recommended I added the (lengthy) source code [which I should have done from the start]. 
Vertex Shader:

```
#define PROCESSING_LIGHT_SHADER
#define MAXWAVES 6

const float pi = 3.14159;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 modelview;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

uniform float time; //Time since shader started

attribute vec4 position; //Position the vertex from Processing
attribute vec4 color; //Color of the vertex from Processing
attribute vec3 normal; //Normal of the vertex from Processing
attribute vec4 ambient;
attribute vec4 specular;
attribute vec4 emissive;
attribute float shininess;

varying vec4 vertColor; //Color passed on to fragment shader
varying vec4 backVertColor; //Color passed on to fragment shader

uniform float waveLength[MAXWAVES]; //Length of wave
uniform float speed[MAXWAVES]; //Cycle speed of wave
uniform float amplitude[MAXWAVES]; //Wave cycle height
uniform float xDirection[MAXWAVES];
uniform float yDirection[MAXWAVES]; //Flow vector of wave

uniform int lightCount;
uniform vec4 lightPosition[8];
uniform vec3 lightNormal[8];
uniform vec3 lightAmbient[8];
uniform vec3 lightDiffuse[8];
uniform vec3 lightSpecular[8];      
uniform vec3 lightFalloff[8];
uniform vec2 lightSpot[8];

varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec3 FragPos;
varying vec3 Vec;
varying vec3 lightDir;

//Some constants that the processing shader used
const float zero_float = 0.0;
const float one_float = 1.0;
const vec3 zero_vec3 = vec3(0);


float falloffFactor(vec3 lightPos, vec3 vertPos, vec3 coeff) {
  vec3 lpv = lightPos - vertPos;
  vec3 dist = vec3(one_float);
  dist.z = dot(lpv, lpv);
  dist.y = sqrt(dist.z);
  return one_float / dot(dist, coeff);
}

float spotFactor(vec3 lightPos, vec3 vertPos, vec3 lightNorm, float minCos, float spotExp) {
  vec3 lpv = normalize(lightPos - vertPos);
  vec3 nln = -one_float * lightNorm;
  float spotCos = dot(nln, lpv);
  return spotCos <= minCos ? zero_float : pow(spotCos, spotExp);
}

float lambertFactor(vec3 lightDir, vec3 vecNormal) {
  return max(zero_float, dot(lightDir, vecNormal));
}

float blinnPhongFactor(vec3 lightDir, vec3 vertPos, vec3 vecNormal, float shine) {
  vec3 np = normalize(vertPos);
  vec3 ldp = normalize(lightDir - np);
  return pow(max(zero_float, dot(ldp, vecNormal)), shine);
}


//Returns the height of a vertex given a single wave param
float WaveHeight(int waveNumber, float x, float y) {
    vec2 direction = (vec2(xDirection[waveNumber], yDirection[waveNumber]));
    float frequency = 2.0*pi/waveLength[waveNumber];
    float phase = speed[waveNumber] * frequency;
    float theta = dot(direction, vec2(x, y));
    return amplitude[waveNumber] * sin(theta * frequency + time * phase);
}

//Returns height of a vertex given all the active waves
// and its current x/y value
float WaveSum(float x, float y)
{
     float height = 0.0;
     for(int i = 0; i < MAXWAVES; i++)
     {
          height += WaveHeight(i, x, y);
     }
     return height;
} 


float getDy(int waveNumber, float x, float y) {
     vec2 direction = (vec2(xDirection[waveNumber], yDirection[waveNumber]));
    float frequency = 2.0*pi/waveLength[waveNumber];
    float phase = speed[waveNumber] * frequency;
    float theta = dot(direction, vec2(x, y));
    float A = amplitude[waveNumber] * direction.y * frequency;
    return A * cos(theta * frequency + time * phase);
}

float getDx(int waveNumber, float x, float y) {
     vec2 direction = (vec2(xDirection[waveNumber], yDirection[waveNumber]));
    float frequency = 2.0*pi/waveLength[waveNumber];
    float phase = speed[waveNumber] * frequency;
    float theta = dot(direction, vec2(x, y));
    float A = amplitude[waveNumber] * direction.x * frequency;
    return A * cos(theta * frequency + time * phase);
}

//Returns the normal vector for each vertex
vec3 getNormal(float x, float y) {
    float dx = 0.0;
    float dy = 0.0;

    //Sum for each wave
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXWAVES; i++) {
        dx += getDx(i, x, y);
        dy += getDy(i, x, y);
    }
    vec3 n = vec3(-dx, -dy, 1.0);
    return normalize(n);
}


void main() {
 vec4 pos = position; //Grab the position from Processing bc it's read only   
  pos.z = WaveSum(pos.x, pos.y);
  gl_Position  = transform * pos; //Get clipping matrix for view

  vec3 ecVertex = vec3(modelview * pos);

  // Normal vector in eye coordinates
  vec3 Normal = getNormal(pos.x, pos.y);
  vec3 ecNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * Normal);

  vec3 ecNormalInv = ecNormal * -one_float;

  // Light calculations
  vec3 totalAmbient = vec3(0, 0, 0);

  vec3 totalFrontDiffuse = vec3(0, 0, 0);
  vec3 totalFrontSpecular = vec3(0, 0, 0);

  vec3 totalBackDiffuse = vec3(0, 0, 0);
  vec3 totalBackSpecular = vec3(0, 0, 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (lightCount == i) break;

    vec3 lightPos = lightPosition[i].xyz;
    bool isDir = lightPosition[i].w < one_float;
    float spotCos = lightSpot[i].x;
    float spotExp = lightSpot[i].y;

    vec3 lightDir;
    float falloff;    
    float spotf;

    if (isDir) {
      falloff = one_float;
      lightDir = -one_float * lightNormal[i];
    } else {
      falloff = falloffFactor(lightPos, ecVertex, lightFalloff[i]);  
      lightDir = normalize(lightPos - ecVertex);
    }

    spotf = spotExp > zero_float ? spotFactor(lightPos, ecVertex, lightNormal[i], 
                                              spotCos, spotExp) 
                                 : one_float;

    if (any(greaterThan(lightAmbient[i], zero_vec3))) {
      totalAmbient       += lightAmbient[i] * falloff;
    }

    if (any(greaterThan(lightDiffuse[i], zero_vec3))) {
      totalFrontDiffuse  += lightDiffuse[i] * falloff * spotf * 
                            lambertFactor(lightDir, ecNormal);
      totalBackDiffuse   += lightDiffuse[i] * falloff * spotf * 
                            lambertFactor(lightDir, ecNormalInv);
    }

    if (any(greaterThan(lightSpecular[i], zero_vec3))) {
      totalFrontSpecular += lightSpecular[i] * falloff * spotf * 
                            blinnPhongFactor(lightDir, ecVertex, ecNormal, shininess);
      totalBackSpecular  += lightSpecular[i] * falloff * spotf * 
                            blinnPhongFactor(lightDir, ecVertex, ecNormalInv, shininess);
    }    
  }    

  // Calculating final color as result of all lights (plus emissive term).
  // Transparency is determined exclusively by the diffuse component.
  vertColor =    
                  vec4(totalFrontDiffuse, 1) * color;

                  backVertColor = 
                  vec4(totalBackDiffuse, 1) * color;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif


varying vec4 vertColor; //Color from vertshader
varying vec4 backVertColor; //Color from vertshader


void main() {        
     gl_FragColor = gl_FrontFacing ? vertColor : backVertColor;
}
```

Comment: You should add relevant code (MCVE) ... and maybe screenshot with the bug you described  (emphasized by colored circle or arrow or something edited in paint or something) so we know exactly what to look for.

Comment: Edited the post to include relevant code at least. It's hard effect to highlight or circle so I figured the gif of the scene would help visualize. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes animation is good but I I usually also take a single screenshot  and edit in a circle box or arrow showing exact area or feature to look at. In your case is not obvious directly what the problem is ... as the joining of shadows might be just due to geometry properties of the waves animation and not a bug. I would try freeze the water  in predefined state (by scrollbar or key progress the animation manualy) and check the shading with moving light direction as you have now that would determine if its really a lighting error and also in which case or just our imagination that its not right.

Comment: By edditng in I mean something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy88t.png

Comment: the light is point light or infinite directional (second ball implies point light)? In both cases its does not look right.  As for point light the dissipation of light should be round and in the other none you got half plane instead. So check your normals and lighting equation. I usually check normals visually like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qpxv.png